# Pushing 2-d Variant data into FormulaArray

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas

I originally had a VBA function that returned a two dimensional variant array:

```
Public Function SplitIntoCells(some_data As String) As Variant()
End Function
```

I used the Formula array syntax to call it from another vba function:

```
Public Function MyWrapper() as Variant
    MyWrapper = SplitIntoCells("somestring")
End Function
```

From Excel, if I select a big enough range and then do:

=MyWrapper()

followed by CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, the data is nicely split into every individual cell in that range.

However in order to automate that, if I change MyWrapper to:

```
Public Function MyWrapper()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E20").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = SplitIntoCells("somestring")
End Function
```

The above doesn't work. I see nothing being displayed in Excel.

What am I doing wrong?

Update:

Just for testing, if I slightly modify MyWrapper() to:

```
Public Function MyWrapper()
    Dim variant_temp() as Variant
    variant_temp = SplitIntoCells("somestring")
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E20").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = variant_temp
End Function
```

variant_temp predictably has the 2-d array after returning from SplitIntoCells but the subsequent Selection.FormulaArray still has nothing in it even after the assignment. I am sure I am missing something blindingly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

A VBA user-defined function cannot modify the cell or range it's being called from: it can only return a value.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Yes: you could run it from an event like worksheet_change or worksheet_selectionchange.  Or just put it in a regular Sub and call it with a button...  Best approach depends on your specific needs.